# How to show date without year of jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to show date with day and month only, but if I set `dateFormat: "d MM"`, I can not change year. It's always 2012. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/v2vcV/. Just try change date for January 2013 and reopen calendar, year will be still 2012.

Comment: If the year isn't being used, what difference does it make which year it shows in the datepicker?

Comment: Because I want to get correctly year using `$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate')`

Comment: You could probably do some chicanery with [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) and [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat).

Comment: @muistooshort so far it's the best solution. Will focus on that — http://jsfiddle.net/Kohver/v2vcV/22/

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small change but it gives you Year also, indeed it removes the bug you were facing

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2vcV/18/)

using this resolves problem     `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd MM yy"});`

You can remove that year logically afterwards when the date is set.

I have made all edit changes and it works great now..[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2vcV/21/)

Enjoy..
:)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.
HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" style="visibility:hidden; width:0px" id="datepicker2"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus(function(){
        $("#datepicker2").focus();
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
    onSelect:function(date){
        $("#datepicker").val(date.substring(0,date.length-4));
        }
    });
});
```

Any way this is not the perfect way but can help what you want(as a illusion). if you want the exact date with year you can get it from datepicker2 textbox.